# python and oracle client on docker image

Tags: docker, cx-oracle, oracleclient

I want to create a docker image with oracle client and cx_oracle of python. I am using multi stage docker to build the image but I am missing an env variable due to which cx_oracle is not able to find an oracle client library.

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
RUN  curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/public-yum-ol7.repo https://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol7.repo && \
     yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient18.3-basic oracle-instantclient18.3-devel oracle-instantclient18.3-sqlplus && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
     echo /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient18.3.conf && \
     ldconfig
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin    

FROM python:slim
COPY ./requirement.txt ./requirement.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirement.txt
COPY --from=0 /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib /root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib
COPY --from=0 /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin /root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin
ENV PATH=$PATH:/root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin:/root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/:$ORACLE_HOME
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RUN echo $PATH
RUN echo $ORACLE_HOME
RUN chmod 755 /root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/*
RUN ls -l /root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib
CMD ["chmod","755","/root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/*"]
CMD ["ls", "-l" ,"/root/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib"]
CMD ["python","test.py"]
```

#### Below is the error

> ```
> DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux
> ```

Comment: You have a mismatch between what you put in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and what you set your environment variables to! You don't need to do both, though. And you definitely don't need to (or want to!) set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Oracle has various Python and cx_Oracle RPMs that you may be able to make use of: https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has Python Dockerfiles at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleLinuxDevelopers

Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1

Comment: Do you know if Oracle has any Windows Docker images? I can't see any at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images I'm looking for an Oracle client with SQL*Plus

Comment: I'm not aware of any.  If you just want to run SQL*Plus, use a Linux container.  If you want something more GUI, then use SQLcl or SQLDeveloper in your own container.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm going to add it manually to my own container. Very poor Windows support from Oracle.

Comment: For Windows, see https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/494#issuecomment-1409659929 for a link to some steps. (Also, as noted in that link, even SQL Server support for Windows Containers was suspended in 2021)